# Mach-O Linker error Duplicate symbol _INIT_NAME in

Tags: c, constants

I have some constants in my project that i want imported to a couple of class files. And when i add the import statement to one i get this error. Ive heard its because ive imported it twice or something but i dont see where or how. Is there any good way to find the error?

**Definitions.h:**

```
const char INIT_NAME = 'A';
const char INIT_ME = 'B';
const char INIT_PLAYER = 'C';
const char ROUND_DATA = 'D';
const char SERVER_IS_FULL = 'E';
const char START_GAME = 'F';
const char START_COUNTDOWN = 'G';
const char READY_1 = 'H';
const char READY_2 = 'I';
const char DROP_PLAYER = 'J';
const char INITIATE_NEW_ROUND = 'K';

const char RIGHT_TURN = 'L';
const char LEFT_TURN = 'M';
const char STOP_TURN = 'N';
const char KILL_PLAYER = 'O';
```

**DataCoder.h**

```
#import "Definitions.h"
```

**Client.h**

```
#import "DataCoder.h"
```

**Server.h**

```
#import "DataCoder.h"
```

When i add the import to datacoder.h i get the error.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the actual error.

Also, in header files, it's common to use header guards to prevent redefining symbols.  For instance:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_FILE_NAME_H
#define MY_HEADER_FILE_NAME_H

const char INIT_NAME='A';
/* snip */
const char KILL_PLAYER='O';

#endif /* MY_HEADER_FILE_NAME_H */
```

Comment: Sorry thought that was the relevant error description. Heres the whole output http://pastebin.com/i67Z9LeP. I tried to just move everthing to my Prefix.pch file in the project (read somewhere that its good for constants) but i still get this error so theres nothing about the imports.

Comment: It's complaining about _NAME from CCActionCamera and CCAction - where is _NAME defined?  Show us that.

Comment: Nowhere i know off, i dont know why it says _NAME, i did a search in my project i i find no such constant.